# Summarise all using which on other column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, min

For some reason, I could not find a solution using the summarise_all function for the following problem:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4), B = 1:8, C = 8:1, D = c(1,2,3,1,2,5,10,9))
```

desired results:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(A) %>% 
    summarise(B = B[which.min(D)],
              C = C[which.min(D)],
              D = D[which.min(D)])
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      A     B     C     D
  <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1     8     1
2     2     2     7     2
3     3     4     5     1
4     4     8     1     9
```

What I tried:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(A) %>% 
    summarise_all(.[which.min(D)])
```

In words, I want to group by a variable and find for each column the value that belongs to the minimum value of another column. I could not find a solution for this using summarise_all. I am searching for a dplyr approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just filter down to the row that has a minimum value of `D` for each level of `A`. The code below assumes there is only one minimum row in each group.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  arrange(D) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

> ```
>       A     B     C     D
> 1     1     1     8     1
> 2     2     2     7     2
> 3     3     4     5     1
> 4     4     8     1     9
> ```

If there can be multiple rows with minimum `D`, then:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4), B = 1:8, C = 8:1, D = c(1,2,3,1,2,5,9,9))

df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  filter(D == min(D))
```

> ```
>       A     B     C     D
> 1     1     1     8     1
> 2     2     2     7     2
> 3     3     4     5     1
> 4     4     7     2     9
> 5     4     8     1     9
> ```

Comment: Or `df %>% arrange(D) %>% distinct(A, .keep_all = TRUE)` .. I think.

Answer (score 1):

You need `filter` - any time you're trying to drop some rows and keep others, that's the verb you want.

```r
df %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(D == min(D))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   A [4]
#>       A     B     C     D
#>   <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     8     1
#> 2     2     2     7     2
#> 3     3     4     5     1
#> 4     4     8     1     9
```